# Why can't use numbers to reference dictionary in Django

Tags: python, django, loops, templates, for-loop

I am trying to render a page with a dictionary, which was created using a loop, and while trying to reference it in the template(.html), it is printing the number inspite of the value for that key

view.py

```
dicti={}
key = range(len(OPTIONS)) # a tuple
for i in key:        
    dicti[i] = polls_model.objects.filter(options=i).count()
dicti.update({'len_of_key' : key})
print(dicti)
return render(request,'polls/thanks.html', dicti)
```

this prints
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 'len_of_key': range(0, 4)}

thanks.html

```
<div class="row">
    {% for i in len_of_key %}
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>
                    {{ i }}
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>            
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and when this runs i end up having 1,2,3,4 in my output.

a little help would be appreciated please

Comment: Do you want to have keys or values in your template to be rendered?

Comment: I want the values in my template to be rendered

Comment: logically, 0,1,2,3, len_of_key are the keys and 1,1,0,0,range(0,4) are the values, so I am trying to reference the values by their keys so using "i" in template. but it is printing just 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to wrap my head around your question. From what I get is that you want to return how many times an option is present.

Firstly, there's no point in doing `range(len(OPTIONS))`
You're better off with

```
for i, key in enumerate(OPTIONS):
    dicti[i] = polls_model.objects.filter(options=i).count()
```

But I doubt that you actually need to filter your polls based on the index of your value. So you might want to change `.filter(options=i)` to `.filter(options=key)`

Next, the values you get back from the model, you shouldn't create separate keys in the dictionary for them. Definitely not if order is important.

Better you create one key where you store the results, this also means the enumerate is obsolete:

```
dicti = {}
dicti['polls'] = []

for key in OPTIONS:
    dict['polls'].append(polls_model.objects.filter(options=key).count())

return render(request, 'polls/thanks.html', dicti)
```

Lastly in the template, your code looks fairly okay, but you should loop over the key we just created instead:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for poll in polls %}
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>
                    {{ poll }}
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>            
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

That should return the count for your polls in the template. If you need to show the length of the polls somewhere, you can use `{{ polls|length }}` instead.

Comment: this solution worked when I replaced key with 'i' in 

dict['polls'].append(polls_model.objects.filter(options=key).count())

Comment: @Pradeep I didn't mention it in the answer, but if you plan to run this with a lot of data you should use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to avoid querying the database too much

Comment: thanks @ghyllebert, I shall use this when running with complex database operations, but this demo application ends with this simple query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
return render(request,'polls/thanks.html', {'dicti': dicti})

{% for key, value in dicti.items %}
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3>
                {{ value }}
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>            
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work, and it is not even interpreting inside the for loop

Comment: This has to work. You just didn't change the `render` statement as indicated in the first line. In your code, there's no context variable `dicti`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your dictionary like this in Django Template.

```
 <div class="row">
        {% for i, j in dicti.items %}
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>
                        {{ j }}
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>            
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work, and it is not even interpreting inside the for loop